# How to add jQuery Datatable Footer in the Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am currently creating my Datatable from my HTML by simply

```
<table class="stripe" width="100%" id="tableId" />
```

In the JS helper, I am setting the parameters and such

```
drawTable : function(dataSet, component){
    var isSortable   = true; 
    var isSearchable = false;
    var showPaging   = true;
    var dispLength   = 15;
    var tableId      = '#TableId';
    var hdrColsArray = '';
    hdrColsArray = ["header1", "header2",...];
    var aryJSONColTable = [];

.
.
.


 for (var i=0; i < hdrColsArray.length; i++ ) {
        var j = i +1;  

        aryJSONColTable.push({
            "sTitle": hdrColsArray[i],
            "targets": i,
            "visible" :true
        });
    };

 $(function(){
        var rows_selected = [];
        table = $(tableId).DataTable({
            "scrollY": "400px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "destroy": true,
            "responsive": true,
            "paging" : showPaging,
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "columnDefs": aryJSONColTable,
            "iDisplayLength": dispLength,
.
.
.
```

How can I add a footer at the bottom to sum up specific columns without having to touch the HTML file. I want to keep just the table element in the file but create the footer from the JS. Is this possible? How would I approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at [Footer callback example](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html)?

Comment: This example seems to explicitly use HTML table definitions thought, right?